# Javascript immutable pop()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got an array:

```
var todo = [{item: name}]
```

What I need to do is `pop()` (or is it shift?) the last item off the array, returning an empty array `[]`.

The issue is, when calling `pop()`, it mutates the array in place, rather than returning a new copy. **How do I return a copy?**

For context, I'm using React and I have a list of things, and it's like a todo list, with buttons for "add another" and "remove", and I need to update the state indirectly.

Comment: Do you have lodash and are you able to use ES6 syntax? If so you can use a lodash method, or [...arr].pop(). If not you can still use slice.

Comment: Is the requirement to return an empty array of return a copy of an element of an array?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
 todo.slice(0, -1)
```

Just slice the last element away.

Answer (score 6):

You can call `slice()` to create a new copy and then mutate the new array

```js
var todo = [
  {item: "itemName1"},
  {item: "itemName2"}
];

var newTodo = todo.slice().pop();
console.log(newTodo);
console.log(todo);
```

Comment: This seems to me by far the most elegant approach.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.pop()` modifies the original array. Use slice to return a new array

```js
var todo = [{item: name}]
var newTodo = todo.slice(0, -1);
console.log(newTodo, todo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice(-1)[0]`.And to avoid the reference a copy use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`. Otherwise changing `copy` will change original

```js
var todo = [{item: 'name2' }, {item: 'name'}]
let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(todo.slice(-1)[0]))
copy.item = "Something else";
console.log(copy)
console.log(todo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Just use the im-mutable `.slice()` to get the last value in the array by passing it a negative (offset), so:

```
todo.slice(-1)
```